# Wait Completed Due to abandoned mutex

Tags: multithreading, mutex, waitone

While running the first instance of the below app it prints "Acquired".
However if i start the second one it waits for 1 min. 
During that interval if press enter and leave the "first instance" it throws *"Wait Completed Due to abandoned mutex"* exception in second instance. 
Is it not suppose to **acquire the thread**?! (As the first instance released it already?!)

```
   using (var m1 = new Mutex(false, "consoleapp"))
        {

            if (!m1.WaitOne(60000, false))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It is already runnig");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Acquired");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
```

Comment: You should explicitly release ownership of the mutex by calling `m1.Release()` in the `else` block. Otherwise it gets disposed but not released, hence the exception thrown by `WaitOne()`.

Comment: Thanks! This explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should explicitly release ownership of the mutex by calling *m1.Release()* in the else block. Otherwise it gets disposed but not released, hence the exception thrown by *WaitOne()* [in Comments by Hristo]